Find values of an array based on an interval
I would like to find values in an array that are at least an interval length apart. Lets say I have the following data set
 0.1 0.21 0.26 0.3 0.36 0.4 0.52 0.76 0.91 1.2

and my interval is 0.25. I need a formula that extracts the each time the data exceeds the interval. The interval starts from the last value that exceeded the previous interval. So the desired output I would like is the following:
0.1 0.36 0.76 1.2

The difficulty is in the 'interval' that is not static. I've tried things with arrayformula and sequence functions but not getting the desired results. Anyone have any pointers for me?

Here's a possible solution. Assuming your values are in A2:A11: *
=UNIQUE(SCAN(A2,A2:A11,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b-a>0.25,b,a))))

* Credit to Chris

An alternative, but a bit more verbose (with formula in B2):
=reduce(A2,A2:A11,lambda(a,c,if(c>chooserows(a,rows(a))+0.25,vstack(a,c),a)))





A
B




1
Data
Result


2
0.1
0.1


3
0.21
0.36


4
0.26
0.76


5
0.3
1.2


6
0.36



7
0.4



8
0.52



9
0.76



10
0.91



11
1.2




or slightly shorter:
=reduce(A2,A2:A11,lambda(a,c,if(c>chooserows(a,-1)+0.25,vstack(a,c),a)))

or (remembering this is Google Sheets, not Excel)
=reduce(A2,A2:A11,lambda(a,c,if(c>chooserows(a,-1)+0.25,{a;c},a)))


Hi @Tom Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
